# Pass all values of an array to a function as arguments

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments, range

How can I pass all of the values of a PHP array to a function as arguments?
I've tried the range() function but that just returns an integer:

```
$obj = new Test();
$arr = array("hello", "hi", "hello");
foreach(range($arr[0], $arr[sizeof($arr)]) as $args) {
    call_user_func_array(array($obj, 'func'), $args);
}

class Test {
    public function func() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        echo $args[0]; // I want that to print "hello"
    }
}

// Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given on line 4
```

Comment: You don't need `foreach`. Simply use: `call_user_func_array(array($obj, 'func'), $arr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$obj = new Test();
$arr = array("hello", "hi", "hello");
call_user_func_array(array($obj, 'func'), $arr);

class Test {
    public function func() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        echo $args[0]; // I want that to print "hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just pass the array then handle it in your `func()` method. e.g.

```
$arr = array('hello','goodbye');

$test = new Test;
$test->func($arr);

class Test {
    public function func($args) {
        echo $args[0]; // I want that to print "hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = new Test();
$arr = array("hello", "hi", "hello");
$obj ->func($arr);
class Test 
{
    public function func($arr) 
    {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
        {
        echo $value."</br>";// Output all the values in array
        }
    echo $arr[0];//To print first value of array  
    }
}
```